# Xcode storyboard issue with auto layout not allowing me to move an objects origin.y value

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, constraints, xcode-storyboard

In my [storyboard](http://i.imgur.com/eUCgWbx.png/) I have just implemented size classes which added perfect constraints to my elements but when trying to modify where the elements y position is located to move it up on the keyboard show event so that it appears attached to the keyboard like [this](http://i.imgur.com/YSJmipg.png/), the elements don't move at all because of the constraints. I have tried removing the constraints, which did not help. From what I've read my understanding of it is if there are no constraints, there are some generated when the app is built. How I used to programmatically move the elements can be seen here: i.imgur.com/uHfgEKl.png . I am asking how do I move the elements y position on the storyboard up with the size of the keyboard while size classes are enabled? If anyone knows how, please inform me.
Sorry the last link is not hyperlinked, I have no reputation as I am new to stack overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

1. Add a *Vertical Space Constraint* for your item and pin it a constant distance from the bottom of the screen.  In *Interface Builder*, place your item near the bottom of the screen, select it, and then select the Auto Layout Pin icon <kbd>|-[]-|</kbd> and turn on the bottom strut.  Set the constant to the initial value you want.  Click <kbd>Add 1 Constraint</kbd>.
2. Add an `@IBOutlet` to the constraint in your code.

   ```
   @IBOutlet weak var verticalSpaceConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
   ```

   You can do this by <kbd>Control</kbd> dragging from the constraint in the *Document Layout View* to your ViewController code.
3. When you need to move your item, change `constant`

   ```
   // Move my item up 100 points
   verticalSpaceConstraint.constant += 100
   ```

---

If you want to animate the constraint change:

```
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    verticalSpaceConstraint.constant += 100
    UIView.animateWithDuration(2.0) {
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
```

Comment: Thank you a lot it is working except for one thing, when the code I had used before executed, it transitioned to the new y. Now with the new code you suggested it snaps straight up to the new value. Is there a way to add a transition effect or should i use a for() statement and increment it one by one to the value so that it looks like it transitions?

Comment: You are really good at Swift. Thank you very much. I know where to come if I have anymore issues.